# Obtain the matrix in a control system with tandem/cascade representation

Tags: control-system, transfer-function

I'm trying to find tandem/cascade and parallel realization for the following transfer function:
$$G(s)=\frac{(s+6)^2}{(s+2)^2(s^2+4s+6)}$$

For Tandem/cascade realization, I draw the following block diagram:

[image]

And there is my resolution attempt:

$$X_1=\frac{1}{s+2}U\Leftrightarrow (s+2)X_1=U\Leftrightarrow sX_1+2X_1=U\xrightarrow {\mathcal{L}} \dot{x_1}+2x_1=u\Leftrightarrow \dot{x_1}=2x_1+u$$

$$W_2=\frac{s^2+12s+36}{s^2+4s+6}X_1$$

$$W_2=\bigg(1+\frac{8s+30}{s^2+4s+6}\bigg)X_1$$

I don't know how to obtain the matrix and the final result. What are the steps that are missing?

Comment: For parallel realization why don't you use partial fractions to deliver an A + B answer?

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for the hint, but my doubt is related with tandem/cascade realization. The parallel realization I know how to do.

Comment: Looking at your block diagram, what else would you need to prove? The block diagram is self evidently a tandem/cascade realization or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @Andyaka I want the matrix with a column $\dot{x_1} ; \dot{x_2} ; \dot{x_3} ; \dot{x_4}$ equals to a matrix with coefficients multiplied for a column with $x_1 ; x_2 ; x_3 ; x_4$ and sum with a column multiplied for the input signal u.

Comment: Why should obtaining the matrix for cascade be much different to parallel (which you say you know how to do)? I might add that I'm out of my depth now and this might be better served on math stack.

Comment: Also, your last formula for \$W_2\$ seems wrong compared the the one directly before.

Comment: Could it be a second order matrix? otherwise you will have to split the equations between 2 first orders. I think you might be able to write a second degree matrix using x ̈

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, you're right. I made a mistake. I rectified the division of polynomials.

Comment: Are you trying to get a state-space realization with \$x_1\$ and \$x_4\$ that match the block diagram, or are you just trying to realize the overall transfer function?  Can you show your state-space realization for just the \$W_2 / X_1\$ part?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to find a state-space representation of a transfer function. There are many ways of doing this and there are a few standard methods called *canonical realizations*. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation#Canonical_realizations) on the subject provides a couple such canonical realizations.